# Make Windows appear to have a custom OS

Tags: windows, google-chrome, operating-system, kiosk

My company just bought some windows tablets to use. I have since designed a webpage that will be the OS. They want me lock out all of the windows features, so how would be the best way to go about doing this?

- I have tried adding using kiosk mode in chrome, but the user can still use windows keys, the task bar, and use Alt+F4.

I also would like if it didn't show the windows lock screen because the employees will be in charge of powering it up. This is so complicated, there are so many things that I will have to disable. If anyone has any tips, or resources please let me know!